# Tag Auto Alignments and Auto Close - HTML

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

How do I have it so that when I open a tag in an HTML file that it will auto close the ending tag and align it properly? I don't see any way to auto close and I also notice that it does not align when closing the tag.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think these are what you're looking for:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=annsk.alignment

Or if you'd like to try another editor, I'd suggest Brackets or sublime(also by using plugins). Brackets has both of those functionalities out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response but those won't help with what I was trying to do. In the end of the day, I am going to stay with Vim.